# shell programing - printf %10s only return 5 spaces

Tags: linux

How come %10s only return 5 spacess. just want to know where the 5 went to

such as printf %s %20s return 15 spaces

Comment: It is 10 for me. A broken implementation, perhaps

Comment: Show the exact command you are running, and your shell and its version. I just tried `printf '.%10s.\n'` with the `printf` being the built-in one inside `zsh 4.3.17` and it works as expected. Same behavior with `/usr/bin/printf` from GNU coreutils 8.13